# Does anyone recognize this fantasy book about a witch’s curse and the quest to break it?

Tags: story-identification, magic

I was young when I read this in the 1980s and have forgotten a lot of it, but I’m hoping someone will recognize it. A vain young man, possibly a noble or prince cursed to be much bigger than he was (I can’t remember if he was also ugly) by a witch that he was rude to, goes on a quest with another young man, who is poor and possibly a servant or his bastard brother (I may be mixing that up with another story) to break the curse. They have many adventures and add to their group but that part of their story is a jumble. I remember that toward the end the only cure for a young woman/companion (possibly kin to the witch) the noble has fallen in love with is a complete blood transfusion, which he thinks will kill him. Because he is so much bigger than her it doesn’t take too much of his blood and he survives. I think his selfless act also breaks the curse.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say that one of the characters was _"cursed to be much bigger than he was,"_ do you mean that he was turned into a giant?

Comment: Hi Ellebeep and welcome to the SFF SE :-) As it happens this book was asked about only a short time ago. It's "The Curse of the Witch-Queen" by Paula Volsky as identified in [Fantasy novel about a noble cursed by a witch-king to become a giant, then has to find a sorceress to cure the witch-king's sick daughter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269328/fantasy-novel-about-a-noble-cursed-by-a-witch-king-to-become-a-giant-then-has-t). Can you confirm this is the correct book, as if so we'll link this question to the previous one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an obvious duplicate of [Fantasy novel about a noble cursed by a witch-king to become a giant, then has to find a sorceress to cure the witch-king's sick daughter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269328/fantasy-novel-about-a-noble-cursed-by-a-witch-king-to-become-a-giant-then-has-t) so I'll add a community wiki answer for the record. The book is [The Curse of the Witch-Queen](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1022228) by Paula Volsky.

[image: The Curse of the Witch-Queen][image: Back cover]

The prince is *Zargal* and the princess is *Bellora*. At the end Zargal asks why the blood transfusion didn't kill him and he is told:

> "Not dead?" King Laza finished for him. "Ordinary you would have been for all of my daughters blood was replaced with blood of yours. But you were not ordinary, you were half again as large as other men and therefore bore a greater quantity of blood."

Comment: That’s it! Thank you so much! I had forgotten that he became a giant, I just knew he was bigger than he had been. As soon as I saw the picture of the cover I remembered more of it. Now, I need to try to find a copy. I appreciate your help, you have made my day.

Comment: As Oprah might say, you get a curse and *you* get a curse....